# When using the flex property image does not scale with its parent div

Tags: html, css

So I am having an issue with my code. When using the "flex property" and setting it to 2 the image will not scale with the div it is in. I know I can alternatively just remove the image from the div set it to have a display of block and it will increase in size due to its given flex property.

However I want to understand what I am doing wrong here, the image is in a div which is a block level element so why is it that when setting the flex property the image will not scale with the div?

```css
body {
  background-color: #696969;
}

.container-1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}

img {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
}

.box-1 {
  flex: 2;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-1">
  <div class="box-1">
    <img src="https://picfiles.alphacoders.com/288/288017.jpg" class="wolf-1">
  </div>
  <div class="box-2">
    <img src="https://picfiles.alphacoders.com/288/288017.jpg" class="wolf-2">
  </div>
  <div class="box-3">
    <img src="https://picfiles.alphacoders.com/288/288017.jpg" class="wolf-3">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: because you are setting a fixed width to your image. Flexbox paly no role here. Whataver the properties, the image will have 400px of width (the one you defined)

Comment: Then how would i counter this?

Comment: you define an adequate width to your image like width:100%

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stratch the image and keep the height add

```
.box-1 img{
  width: 100%;
}
```

If you want to keep a proper photo proportions add

```
.box-1 img{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #696969;
}

.container-1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}

img {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
}

.box-1 {
  flex: 2;
  background-color: blue;
}

.box-1 img{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-1">
  <div class="box-1">
    <img src="https://picfiles.alphacoders.com/288/288017.jpg" class="wolf-1">
  </div>
  <div class="box-2">
    <img src="https://picfiles.alphacoders.com/288/288017.jpg" class="wolf-2">
  </div>
  <div class="box-3">
    <img src="https://picfiles.alphacoders.com/288/288017.jpg" class="wolf-3">
  </div>
</div>
```